# system() not working in php using windows server 2003

Tags: php, iis-6, windows-server-2003

i have to extract the cabfile(.cab) on the server.
i am Finding such script which extract cab file but i didn't get it yet.
So now i am try to extract using cabarc.exe.
But i face the problem that when i run command throuw commandline its work fine but when i give same command to system() or exec() function in php it is not work.
code is as follow:

```
    $command = "c:\\exe\\cabarc X c:\\cab\\data.cab c:\\data\\";
if(($output = system($command,$return) != false)
{
  echo "$return";
}
```

it is not working when i use same string in commandline it works fine.
please any body help me to why it not working what to do tomake it work is ther any rights issue.
I had give the execute permission to the site.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument to the [system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function is passed by reference so it needs to be initialized by your code. Also, you should check for false using `!==` not `!=` because it validates type in addition to value. Additionally, it looks like you've got an unbalanced parenthesis in your `if` statement. Try this:

```
$command = "c:\\exe\\cabarc X c:\\cab\\data.cab c:\\data\\";
$return = -1;
$output = system($command, $return);
if($output !== false)
{
    echo "Return value is: " . $return . "\r\n";
    echo "Output is:\r\n" . $output . "\r\n";
}
```

If that doesn't fix your issue, make sure the PHP user has permissions to access the file.

Comment: Thanks Asaph for reply
I have followed your suggestion. but my problem is still remaining.
I have gave full control to the site and folder.
but it doesn't work.
Is ther any problem in php and iis?
thanks for help

Comment: @jazzy: Try running the PHP program outside of IIS. Try running the PHP program directly on the console.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NTFS, check your file permissions and make sure the web server can run that executable, open the source file, and write the destination.

Answer (score 1):

Another problem might be that the program is not allowed to run cmd.exe, maybe see if the IUSR account can execute this program as system needs to invoke a shell.